# Sum elements of list ignoring NaN without numpy

Tags: python, list, sum

I can't use numpy, how can I emulate .nansum method? Example

```
x = [1, NaN, 2, 10]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a generator expression to `sum` that uses `math.isnan` to ignore NaN elements.

```py
from math import isnan
print(sum(e for e in x if not isnan(e)))
```

Alternatively, using the fact that NaN is not equal to itself:

```py
print(sum(e for e in x if e == e))
```